# How to use Intrinsic functions in Fn::Sub for SecondaryLevel Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use FN::Sub to construct the secondary level key as per below. The validator will only accept a string. What am I missing?

"ImageId": {"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, {"Fn::Sub": "AMI${SQLServerVersion}"} ]} ,

Answer (score 0):

In the hope it will save some time for others, there a 2 important findings re Fn::FindInMap

1. The Secondary Key may only contain alpha numeric characters (no - or _, etc)
2. Only supports "Ref" function

With these limitations, I added a mapping

```
  "SQLServerMap": {        
    "eu-west-1": {
      "2008": "ami-14b4446d",
      "2012": "ami-5fd72526",
      "2016": "ami-8b7f8ef2" 
    }
  }
```

then the template now validates with

"ImageId": {"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "SQLServerMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, { "Ref" : "SQLServerVersion" } ]}

Comment: One correction on 2, `Fn::FindInMap` only supports `Ref` And `Fn::FindInMap` as per the docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html#w2ab2c21c28c22c13)